# I verified my app How to Fix "This app isn't verfied" using google sheet

Tags: php

My app google sheet verified but i using receive alert "This app isn't verifed"

This is running php flatform

I expect the output skip "This app isn't verifed" but i actual output "This app isn't verifed"

Please help me!